# jupyter notebook display cells horizontal

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I have issues on jupyter notebook conversion. It looks fine on jupyter notebook. However if I convert it to html or upload to github, it displays like photo above.
Instead of vertical(scroll up and down), I have to scroll left and right and each cell are really narrowed. 
Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is typical of a library you use emitting invalid HTML. I would suggest opening an issue or contacting the Jupyter mailing list to help you debug this as StackOverflow will not be the right place to have a back and forth.

You should be able to narrow down which library does that by:
 - backup your notebook. 
 - Delete cells one and until notebook looks normal. (tip use nbconvert locally instead of uploading, and use `python -m http.server`)
 - the last cell you delete have a issue.

It may be a bug in nbconvert but I doubt it.

Comment: Even nbconverter displays same way. But I will let Jupyter community know this issue. Thank you