# Jupyter notebook does not display correctly on github

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

Here is my notebook:
https://gist.github.com/tung2389/772de25aede8bcf0c2a1e6251fa45063

When I open my notebook in Jupyter, it looks fine:

[image: r]

But when I upload my notebook to GitHub or viewing it is using https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/, it looks weird:

[image]

In my notebook, I only use matplotlib version 3.3.0, numpy 1.19.1 and pandas 1.0.5

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What version of juypter are you using locally? Are you using Jupyter Widgets?

Comment: I am using Jupyter notebook 6.0.1 in anaconda, with Python 3.7.4.  I'm not using Jupyter Widgets.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701085/jupyter-notebook-display-cells-horizontal